# get property of a dataobject in refernce to other property of same object in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, events, data-objects

how to get the speed property of 'smokeobject' inside a enter_frame listener 'animatesmoke' in reference to the movieclip 'whitesmoke' which is also a property of 'smokeobject

here is my code

```
public function createRocketSmoke() 
    {
        var smokeObject:Object = new Object();
         smokeObject.whiteSmoke = new Bitmap(new WhiteSmoke(0,0));
         smokeObject.whiteSmoke.x=targetX + Math.random()*4-8;
         smokeObject.whiteSmoke.y=targetY + Math.random()*4-8;

        smokeContainer=new MovieClip();
        smokeContainer.addChild(smokeObject.whiteSmoke);
        addChild(smokeContainer);

        var randomScale = Math.random();
        if(randomScale<.5)
        randomScale = randomScale+.5;
        smokeObject.whiteSmoke.scaleX= randomScale;
        smokeObject.whiteSmoke.scaleY= randomScale;
        smokeObject.speed = Math.random();
        smokeObject.whiteSmoke.rotation = Math.random()*360;
        smokeObject.whiteSmoke.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,animateSmoke);    

    }
    public function animateSmoke(event:Event):void
    {
        //here i want the speed property of the 'smokeObject'
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is going to get extremely messy very quickly.

I suggest creating a class for your Smoke and giving it an `update()` function:

```
public class Smoke
{

    // Properties.
    private var _whiteSmoke:Bitmap;
    private var _speed:Number = 0;


    // Constructor.
    public function Smoke(targetX:Number = 0, targetY:Number = 0)
    {
        // Prepare graphics.
        _whiteSmoke = new Bitmap(new WhiteSmoke());
        _whiteSmoke.x = targetX + Math.random()*4-8;
        _whiteSmoke. y = targetY + Math.random()*4-8;
        _whiteSmoke.rotation = Math.random()*360;
        _whiteSmoke.scaleX = whiteSmoke.scaleY = 0.5 Math.random() * 0.5;

        // Apply random speed.
        _speed = Math.random();
    }


    // Update this smoke.
    public function update():void
    {
        //
        // Update this smoke here.
        //
    }


    // The graphics for this smoke.
    public function get whiteSmoke():Bitmap
    {
        return _whiteSmoke;
    }


    // The speed for this smoke.
    public function get speed():Number
    {
        return _speed;
    }

}
```

This will allow you to more easily update your smoke objects with an array and a loop to update each of them:

```
// This array will hold all your Smoke objects.
var allSmoke:Array = [];

// Create some Smoke.
var smoke1:Smoke = new Smoke(10, 10);
var smoke2:Smoke = new Smoke(10, 10);

// Add it to the array.
allSmoke.push(smoke1);
allSmoke.push(smoke2);


// Prepare game loop.
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
function update(e:Event):void
{
    // Loop through smoke objects and update them.
    for each(var i:Smoke in allSmoke)
    {
        i.update();
    }
}
```